# Type guards for types with the same fields

Tags: typescript, typing, structural-typing

I stumbled into a limitation of structural typing and wondered if there was a way round it.

Suppose I have a hierarchy of types as follows:

```js
type Message = HelloMessage | GoodbyeMessage

type HelloMessage = {
  message: string
}

type GoodbyeMessage = {
  message: string
}
```

and we define some type guards as follows:

```js
function isHello(value: any): value is HelloMessage {
    return !!value && !!value.message && typeof value.message === "string" && value.message.includes("hello")
}

function isGoodbye(value: any): value is GoodbyeMessage {
    return !!value && !!value.message && typeof value.message === "string" && value.message.includes("goodbye")
}
```

Attempting to use the type guards in a function leads to subsequent uses being typed as `never` by the compiler:

```
function someFunc(input: Message): string {
    if (isHello(input)) {
        return input.message
    }
    if (isGoodbye(input)) {
        return input.message // compiler errors here
    }
    return "unknown"
}
```

Some obvious solutions are to type the input as `any` or cast `input` as `GoodbyeMessage` inside the `if` statement, but neither of these feel particularly elegant.
Is this simply a limitation of Typescript's structural nature of `type` or is there some other magic that can be incanted to make it work as I'm expecting?

Comment: Maybe this is subjective, but I wouldn't call this a "limitation" of structural typing; it's a *feature*. `HelloMessage` and `GoodbyeMessage` are just two names for the same type; if you want two types to be distinct they should be structurally distinct, otherwise you're trying to write a function that can distinguish between, say, Samuel Clemens and Mark Twain.  The compiler is telling you that you will never have one without the other.  ...

Comment: ... So, using your type guard implementation as a guide, I'd suggest that you really want to use something like a template literal type for the `message` property, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaE8nN).  Now the compiler actually sees that the two types are structurally distinct, and it works as expected, I think.  If that fully addresses your question I could write up an answer explaining.  Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: To be clear, I created the example code purely for demonstration purposes, the real type hierarchy contains more types and some of them have different fields, but they are parsed depending on an external field

Comment: If the demo isn't a [mre] then it's hard to advise; if your actual types have differing fields then the question might want to say that (although I guess that would completely invalidate the premise of the question so maybe not?).  To the extent that you can't structurally distinguish two types that need to be nominally distinct you could use [branding](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible) as a workaround (what you called "phantom" below); do you want to see that written up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, this is a limitation of the typing system. Even if the type guards worked, you couldn't *actually* tell if a function was passed `HelloMessage` or `GoodbyeMessage`, since all it sees is `{ message: string }`. You could instead use a tagged union type, which **can** be discriminated with type guards:

```js
type Message = HelloMessage | GoodbyeMessage;

type HelloMessage = {
  type: "hello";
  message: string;
}

type GoodbyeMessage = {
  type: "goodbye";
  message: string;
}

// Prefer to use `unknown` for additional type safety.
function isHello(value: unknown): value is HelloMessage {
  return typeof value === "object"
      && value !== null
      && "type" in value
      && typeof value.type === "string"
      && value.type === "hello";
}

function isGoodbye(value: unknown): value is GoodbyeMessage {
  return typeof value === "object"
      && value !== null
      && "type" in value
      && typeof value.type === "string"
      && value.type === "goodbye";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the unknown tip, that's a good point!
I resorted to a tagged union of sorts in the end (passing a `_phantom` field, although callers could still technically use it which kinda sucks - would be cool if phantom types existed in Typescript and I finally had a use case for them ;p)